# Существование события в браузере

Tags: javascript

Как можно проверить поддержку браузером, открывшего сайт, возможности работы с определенным *стандартным* событием, например, `transitionend`, `focusin` или даже `beforecopy`, ведь однозначно они поддерживаются не всеми браузерами и хотелось бы узнать вовремя, что они корректно обработаются.

Особенно интересует, как узнать, поддерживает ли браузер событие `transitionend`, это событие берёт свои истоки из CSS, поэтому с ним надо видимо работать как-то по-другому. Можно ли сказать так: если у него есть свойство `transition`, то у него есть событие и `transitionend`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует специальная библиотека для [проверки всего-всего](https://modernizr.com/). Там это делают вот так:

1. берется имя события;
2. конкатенируют `'on'` и имя этого события;
3. проверяем наличие свойства с получившимся именем у элемента, например `div`'а, с помощью оператора `in`. Если такое свойство есть, тогда событие может обрабатываться;
4. для странных браузеров, для уверенности, берут этот элемент и добавляют к нему пустой атрибут с именем, получившимся в результате конкатенации. Если у этого DOM-объекта появилось свойство с таким именем, которое является функцией, тогда событие может обрабатываться (думаю этот пункт можно смело опускать).

Пример такой функции:

```
function hasEvent(event, elem) {
    var event = 'on' + event;
    var elem = document.createElement(elem || 'div');

    var has = event in elem;
    if (!has) {
        elem.setAttribute(event, '');
        has = typeof elem[event] == 'function';
    }

    return has; 
}
```

Или, немного ее сократив, вот так:

```
function hasEvent(event, elem) {
    return ('on' + event) in document.createElement(elem || 'div');
}
```

Пример работы:

```
hasEvent('click');  // true
hasEvent('azaza');  // false
```

Соответственно, второй аргумент существует для того, чтобы можно было проверить специфичные для некоторых DOM-объектов свойства.

Всё было бы здорово, **но** такой метод работает *некорректно*, например, на `transitionend` он всегда говорит `false`.

Похоже единственный способ узнать, есть ли какой `transitionend` в браузере, асинхронный, увы, что не очень удобно и состоит в том, чтобы просто инициализировать событие, в котором изменить некий флаг, то есть вот так:

```
var hasTransition = false;
function getHasTransition() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    div.style.transition = 'transform 1ms ease';

    document.body.appendChild(div);

    div.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
        hasTransition = true;
        alert('yes');
        document.body.removeChild(div);
    });

    setTimeout(function() { div.style.transform = 'translateX(1px)'; }, 20);
}
```

Какое-то некрасивое решение, однако, другие не приходят в голову. Модифицировать его на проверку всяких префиксов не представляет труда. Узнавать поддержку браузером `transitionend` асинхронно не хорошо. Видимо лучше просто положиться на проверку наличия свойства `elem.style.transition` (и прочих) и считать, что события есть автоматом.